# Is there a way to teach gtest to print user-defined types using libfmt's formatter?

Tags: c++, c++17, googletest

I'm wondering if there is a way to make gtest understand a user-defined types libfmt's formatter, for the means of printing a readable error output?
I know how I can teach gtest to understand user-defined types via adding the stream insertion operator `operator<<` for this very user-defined type, e.g.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, CpuTimes const& anything);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, CpuStats const& anything);
```

This is well documented [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#teaching-googletest-how-to-print-your-values).

But I heavily use libfmt, which requires a formatting function to be implemented to produce a readable and printable output of a user-defined type. This so-called `fmt::formatter` is actually a template specialization, e.g.

```
namespace fmt {

template <> struct formatter<CpuTimes> : basics::fmt::ParseContextEmpty {
    format_context::iterator format(CpuTimes const& times, format_context& ctx);
};
template <> struct formatter<CpuStats> : basics::fmt::ParseContextEmpty {
    format_context::iterator format(CpuStats const& stats, format_context& ctx);
};
template <> struct formatter<CpuLimits> : basics::fmt::ParseContextEmpty {
    format_context::iterator format(CpuLimits const& limits, format_context& ctx);
};
} // namespace fmt
```

For gtest to understand this format, you have to write the same implementation for the `operator<<` over and over for every type you want gtest to print properly, like

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, CpuTimes const& anything) {
    return stream << fmt::format("{}", anything);
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, CpuStats const& anything) {
    return stream << fmt::format("{}", anything);
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, CpuLimits const& anything) {
    return stream << fmt::format("{}", anything);
}
```

Is there a way to spare my writing this boilerplate code?

Comment: Is it possible to just use a `template`d `operator<<` or `PrintTo` function that generically does `stream << std::format("{}", v)`?

Comment: @Human-Compiler at first idea looks good, but when you try it ambiguity kicks in: https://godbolt.org/z/51vsqo5bo so it is not so strait forward. I think proper use of namespaces can save this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid problems caused by ambiguity of `PrintTo` or `operator<<` namespace is needed.

Here is [some demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1zrxqz8TY) when namespaces is used:

```cpp
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

namespace me {
struct Foo {
    int x = 0;
    double y = 0;
};

bool operator==(const Foo& a, const Foo& b)
{
    return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
}
}

template <>
struct fmt::formatter<me::Foo> {
    char presentation = 'f';

    constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) -> decltype(ctx.begin())
    {
        auto it = ctx.begin(), end = ctx.end();
        if (it != end && (*it == 'f' || *it == 'e'))
            presentation = *it++;
        if (it != end && *it != '}')
            throw format_error("invalid format");
        return it;
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const me::Foo& p, FormatContext& ctx) -> decltype(ctx.out())
    {
        return presentation == 'f'
            ? format_to(ctx.out(), "({}, {:.1f})", p.x, p.y)
            : format_to(ctx.out(), "({}, {:.1e})", p.x, p.y);
    }
};

#if VERSION == 1

namespace me {
template <typename T>
void PrintTo(const T& value, ::std::ostream* os)
{
    *os << fmt::format(FMT_STRING("{}"), value);
}
}

#elif VERSION == 2

namespace me {
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T& value)
{
    ::std::operator<<(out, fmt::format(FMT_STRING("{}"), value));
    return out;
}
}
#endif

class MagicTest : public testing::Test { };

TEST_F(MagicTest, CheckFmtFormater)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(fmt::format("{}", me::Foo {}), "(0, 0.0)");
}

TEST_F(MagicTest, FailOnPurpuse)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(me::Foo {}, (me::Foo { 1, 0 }));
}
```

Dropping `me` namespace cause all implementations to [have ambiguity problems](https://godbolt.org/z/PW1sE3bhM).

Note that namespace causes that [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) is used.

Comment: It actually boils down to use the `operator<<` (ambiguity with `PrintTo` seems not really resolvable) and that you access the `operator<<` in the template using namespace `std`. While using it like this `stream << fmt::format("{}", value)` will show again ambiguity, but writing the operator this way `std::operator<<(stream, fmt::format("{}", value)` will solve the problem. Thanks @MarekR, for pointing to the right direction! Find here [my example](https://godbolt.org/z/vK6j4eqhM), based on your template.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already went thru the trouble of instantiating the `fmt::formatter` stuff, this was my solution to enable all of the things in the `MYSTUFF` namespace to automatically get the `operator<<` I think you're asking for:

```cpp
// In your template specialization of fmt::formatter<>:
using isCustomFormatter = std::true_type;

// then later...
namespace MYSTUFF {

template<typename T>
concept HasCustomFormatter = requires { 
    typename fmt::formatter<T>::isCustomFormatter; 
};

template <HasCustomFormatter T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T& val)
{
    ::std::operator<<(out, fmt::format("{}", val));
    return out;
}

} // MYSTUFF
```